# pandas dataframe, skip index if condition is meet

Tags: python, pandas

I want to skip the index of a data frame output only if specific conditions are met. `A` it's a special id for seller. `B` it's the selling price. Type is selling type.

```
import pandas

Data= []
Data+=[{"A": "ID_1", "Special":{"type": "USD"},"B": "0.11",}]
Data+=[{"A": "ID_2", "Special":{"type": "EUR"},"B": "0.122",}]
Data+=[{"A": "ID_3", "Special":{"type": "EUR"},"B": "0.1444",}]

Data = pandas.DataFrame(Data)
Data = Data.sort_values(by=['B'], ascending=False)

seller = Data['A'][Data.index[-1]]
price  = Data['B'][Data.index[-1]]

print('{} {}'.format(seller, price))
```

As you can see, I will have many records, pandas will iterate data and assign an index for each `{ ... }` also will be sorted based on B value which is price, it will display the lowest price.

Want I want is a check to display the lowest price AND seller just if the type is EUR (Ignore all records that have type USD)... How I can do that? I tried to explain as well as I can... Thanks.

Online compileable example:  https://www.online-python.com/Bxj2OY3els

Comment: `Data` is not valid. Please make sure your code is free from syntax errors.

Comment: Allright, i recheck

Comment: https://www.online-python.com/Bxj2OY3els

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
import pandas

Data= []
Data+=[{"A": "X1FFFFF", "Special":{"type": "USD"},"B": "0.11",}]
Data+=[{"A": "X2FFFFF", "Special":{"type": "EUR"},"B": "0.122",}]
Data+=[{"A": "X3FFFFF", "Special":{"type": "EUR"},"B": "0.1444",}]

#all data in Special are strings, simulate by astype(str)
Data = pandas.DataFrame(Data).astype(str)

Data = Data.astype({"B": float})
Data = Data.astype({"A": str})

import ast

#convert to dicts if necessary
Data["Special"] = Data["Special"].apply(ast.literal_eval)

#filtering `type` for `EUR`
euro_rows = Data.loc[Data["Special"].str.get('type') == 'EUR']

#get minimal value and index (A) by minimal
lowest_price = euro_rows.set_index('A')['B']

seller = lowest_price.idxmin()
price  = lowest_price.min()

print(seller)
X2FFFFF

print(price)
0.122
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this:

```
# gets only the Euro type
euro_rows = Data.loc[Data["Special"] == {'type': 'EUR'}]

# gets the row of the lowest price
lowest_price = euro_rows.loc[euro_rows['B'] == euro_rows['B'].min()]

# gets seller and price
seller, price = lowest_price['A'].item(), lowest_price['B'].item()

print(seller) #prints: IDDDDDDDDDDD
print(price)  #prints: 0.1
```

Comment: in your `Fuck.py` file :D, you are using `Data['A'].item()` instaed of `lowest_price['A'].item()`... I think that's the problem

Answer (score 1):

It might be better for you to read your data using `pd.json_normalize` before filtering to get what you need:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(Data).astype({"B": float})

#to get the row with the lowest price
>>> df[df["Special.type"]=="EUR"].nsmallest(1, "B")
      A      B Special.type
1  ID_2  0.122          EUR
```