# Python error: ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which select lowest price and seller from an json. However sometimes i get this error: `ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar` it happens just sometimes, not always.

Here is the code..

```
import pandas

Data= []
Data+=[{"A": "X1FFFFF", "Special":{"type": "USD"},"B": "0.11",}]
Data+=[{"A": "X2FFFFF", "Special":{"type": "EUR"},"B": "0.122",}]
Data+=[{"A": "X3FFFFF", "Special":{"type": "EUR"},"B": "0.1444",}]

Data = pandas.DataFrame(Data)
Data = Data.astype({"B": float})
Data = Data.astype({"A": str})

euro_rows = Data.loc[Data["Special"] == {'type': 'EUR'}]

lowest_price = euro_rows.loc[euro_rows['B'] == euro_rows['B'].min()]

seller = lowest_price['A'].item()
price  = lowest_price['B'].item()

print(seller)
print(price)
```

what i can do to fix that error?

Full error :

```
  File "Fuck.py", line 50, in GetLowestPriceAndSeller
    seller = lowest_price['seller'].item()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 420, in item
    raise ValueError("can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar")
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select first value if always exist at least one value:

```
seller = lowest_price['A'].iat[0]
price  = lowest_price['B'].iat[0]
```

If possible sometimes first value not exist, because `lowest_price` is empty is possible use this trick for specify default value with `iter` with `next`:

```
seller = next(iter(lowest_price['A']), 'default')
price  = next(iter(lowest_price['B']), 'default')
```

Alternative solution is convert `A` to index and then get minimal of `B` and index (`A`) by minimal value by [`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
lowest_price = euro_rows.set_index('A')['B']

seller = lowest_price.idxmin()
price  = lowest_price.min()

print(seller)
print(price)
```

Comment: it's not possible that value to be empty (i make sure that value isnt empty), and still same error even with  .iat[0]

Comment: @IrinelIovan - What is error?

Comment: File "Fuck.py", line 50, in GetLowestPriceAndSeller
    seller = lowest_price['seller'].item().iat[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 420, in item
    raise ValueError("can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar")
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

Comment: @IrinelIovan - code is different, without `.item()`

Comment: File "Fuck.py", line 50, in GetLowestPriceAndSeller
    seller = lowest_price['seller'].iat[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2103, in __getitem__
    return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 958, in _get_value
    return self._values[label]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: @IrinelIovan - yes, it means emty dataframe, need second solution in my answer.

Comment: that's the strange thing, dataframe isn't empty.. I checked output of dataframe and isnt empty

Comment: @IrinelIovan - do you test `print (lowest_price)` ?

Comment: Here is output of dataframe:  https://pastebin.com/yJvxNzLZ

Comment: When i want print seller it throws this:  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Fuck.py", line 88, in <module>
    GetLowestPriceAndSeller()
  File "Fuck.py", line 50, in GetLowestPriceAndSeller
    seller = lowest_price['seller'].item()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 420, in item
    raise ValueError("can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar")
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar, Just seller seems is not working

Comment: @IrinelIovan - interesting, no idea, but added alternative solution to answer.

Comment: File "Fuck.py", line 51, in GetLowestPriceAndSeller
    seller = lowest_price.idxmin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2103, in idxmin
    i = nanops.nanargmin(self._values, skipna=skipna)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py", line 73, in _f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py", line 1074, in nanargmin
    result = values.argmin(axis)
ValueError: attempt to get argmin of an empty sequence

Comment: It seems like u said, it says dataframe empty.. but very strange  because datafram is filled

Comment: Can you please check this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69369824/pandas-dataframe-skip-index-if-condition-is-meet  maybe the guy who answered me did something wrong based on my previous question ?

Comment: seems filtration failed, it return emty data in your real data `Data.loc[Data["Special"] == {'type': 'EUR'}]`

Comment: If u have a better way to achieve what I need in the previous post question, please answer me. The DataFram is for sure filled and contain data, maybe that guy code has some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, that you have several items in lowest_price, which might be possible if they cost exactly the same, which would also explain, why it is only happening sometimes.

So the culprit is probably the call to .item(), which expects a single item, but you have an array in there.

You could then simple take the whole lowest_price array instead of just the item. This depends a bit on what you exactly want to do with the data, because in my opinion the circumstances change a bit from what you originally had.